# Google Drive queryForFilesList not returning any results

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm currently having issues with the iOS Google Drive SDK. I'm using [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/queries) to search for a file in my Google Drive. All the files I want have a path in the format *directory-name*/*file-name*. Since the SDK/API doesn't allow searching for files using a full path, I'm using the following query to ultimately get it's downloadUrl. I'm using a query in the following format:

```
((title = 'directory-name') AND ('root' in parents) AND (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder')) OR
((title = 'file-name') AND (not 'root' in parents) AND (mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'))
```

The first line is meant to find all directories in the root directory whose name matches mine, and the second line should match all files with the same name. This should return the directory i'm looking for, the file i'm looking for, and maybe some other stuff (e.g. files with the same name in other directories). I have some code to figure out which file is the correct one.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes I get no results from the query. This generally happens after I rename the file, and rename it back, or other things like that. The weird part is that if I run either of the two lines of the query independently, it returns correctly, but together they don't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I would gladly provide more information if required.

And yes, I'm using the kGTLAuthScopeDrive scope.

The ideal solution would be if I could just search using a full path, so if there's a way to do this, then I'm not aware.

Comment: is there some reason that you use `mimeType` not folder, instead of ...`(mimeType = application/vnd.google-apps.file)`? Also do you wrap the entire query in brackets?

Comment: i didn't know you could use that mime type. i just figure "not folder" would encompass all files.

Comment: i do not wrap it in brackets. is this something i should be doing?

Comment: Rob the brackets is me being pedantic. As long as you include the entire string in @"..." you should be fine with the format as is shown in your code. Here is a link to the different [MIME types for Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types). Again not folder should also work fine - I was just curious about you using that method.

Comment: Here is my attempt at a more helpful question... From my experience when the populated variable comes back in the completion handler (e.g. `<instance of GTLDriveService> executeQuery:<your query> completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFileList *fileList, NSError *error) {`), I like to use the `fileList.identifier` to maintain a persistent reference to each file, because even if the name of the file and/or folder changes, that identifier remains the same. Have you tried that?

Comment: Keeping the identifier is the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish. If the file gets renamed or moved elsewhere, I don't care about it anymore. In my scenario, the file will be constantly be updated, while the "old file" will be archived, so I want access to the "fresh" data while the archived file (which is what the identifier would store) becomes irrelevant. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was unable to get this to work. And also unfortunately, Google does not provide an API to query for a full path. So I resorted to iterating over the path to get the directory IDs, and then when I get to the file, get its ID and download it. Although slightly more complex, my solution was based on this question and chosen answer: [What's the right way to find files by "full path" in Google Drive API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266168/whats-the-right-way-to-find-files-by-full-path-in-google-drive-api-v2)

Comment: 2015 here. This still doesn't work. Why, Google. Why.

Comment: Wait, I take that back. It's working. Thanks Google!